# how to combine rows with a key and keep the latest value if not null using python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

if I have Patient data sorted by date and I need the combined latest nonnull during each month with each other
[data before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtYOc.png)

here I tried to combine them like this so in the same month for each column I need the latest nonnull value
[Data after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU5wM.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by building your dataframe, df:

```
import pandas as pd
month = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2]
date = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-02-01','2020-02-02','2020-02-03']
BP = [120, 122, None, 200, 150, None, None]
temp = [36, None, None, None, 36, 37, None]
weight = [None, None, 55, None, None, None,56]

df = pd.DataFrame({'month':month,
                   'date':date,
                   'BP': BP,
                   'temp': temp,
                   'weight': weight})
df
```

[image]

You want to group your dataframe by month, and pick the last non null value of the other columns (except date):

```
df1 = df.groupby('month', as_index=False)[['BP','temp','weight']].last()
df1
```

[image]